Any ways to compare a request's response using JMeter plugin
Is it possible to compare the JMeter response from the previous run with the one being run now, and then add a rule set to remove a specific key or param from the response which does not take that param while comparing both the response using JMeter plugin?
I've tried using the comparison assertion, which is a complicated method since if we enter a regex pattern incorrectly, the case fails overall and we don't know in which point it fails. Moreover, by doing this, we are unable to compare previously and currently ran.
[Refer compare assertion here]: https://i.sstatic.net/bZQoBgWU.png

Maybe it would be better to store responses into files and then compare the files contents?
It looks like you response type is JSON and JSR223 Test Elements with Groovy language have built-in JSON support. You can also write response into a file using JSR223 Post-Processor, Assertion or Listener and remove any attributes which are not needed or which supposed to have different values.
More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?
